# Powershell excel paste vaule

Tags: powershell

I have one excel file with a few sheets in it. Im trying to combine all of them into one sheet. I have code that does this, but the issue im having now is now the sheets have formulas on them. So when it copies to the new sheet it doesnt copy over the values, but copies the formulas. I was reading online you can do this pastespecial, but i cant get it working. Does anyone have code on how can i copy one sheet to another, but keep the values. The one issue is the sheets have differnt amount of rows so im not sure how what the range would be. I have tried many things and i just can figure it out.

This is using the excel.application

To questions, the thing is i cant figure out the .PasteSpecial.

Here is the code now that copies it to a sheet called combine.

```
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($location)
$newSheetName = 'Combine'
$xlCellTypeLastCell = 11
$targetSheet = $wb.Sheets.Add()
$targetSheet.Name = $newSheetName
$includeHeader = $true
foreach ($sh in $wb.Sheets) {
        $statename = $sh.Name
        if($sh.name -eq "Available" -or $sh.name -eq "Eligible"){
        }else{
        $sh.autofiltermode = $false
        $sourceRange = $sh.UsedRange
        if ($sourceRange.Rows.Count -le 1) { continue }
        # if ($sourceRange.Rows.Count -le 1 -or $sh.Name -eq $newSheetName) {continue}
        $targetLastCell = $targetSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells($xlCellTypeLastCell)
        if ($includeHeader) {
            [Void]$sourceRange.PasteSpecial($targetLastCell)
        }
        else {
            $columnOffset = - $targetLastCell.Column + 1
            $targetCell = $targetLastCell.Offset(1, $columnOffset)
            $newRowCount = $sourceRange.Rows.Count - 1
            [Void]$sourceRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize($newRowCount).Copy($targetCell)
        }
        $includeHeader = $false
}
}
```

This does work with headers, but at this point i dont really care about those. I will say UsedRange also misses me up. So right now it i just use the .copy and from reading online i need to use the pasteSpecial.

Comment: Remember that nobody can see your code or your screen.

Comment: Have you tried `.PasteSpecial('xlPasteValues')`? Please show the relevant code and any errors it produces, and describe the performed behavior vs the desired behavior.

Comment: I  have edited the question.

Comment: got it figured out.